# MVC ASP.NET 2 - Wizard through array of items

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am after a little advice. I am new to MVC and have been trying to put together a sample application that uses a web service to get the data. The data is being returned from a Microsoft Navision database.
One screen that I was hoping to put together was a Wizard that allowed the user to go backwards and forwards through a list of Items and to collate all the amendments made together before submitting back to the database through exposed web service.
My thinking on this was to minimise web service calls.

I have followed Steven Sandersons - Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework book and he has a section about wizards and serializing and deserializing objects across the various Contollers, but in my case I was hoping to call the same Controller but with maybe a different index number to show the correct Item record. The View would have a strongly typed reference to a List.

Please can you advise whether this is just not the right way to go about this or whether it would indeed be possible.

Many Thanks

pf79

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for any answers but I think I have found an answer. I was trying to keep it server-side as I may be using this on a windows 6 mobile device and also I'm not really used javascript before;

Using a combination of TempData and Serialization I am able to achieve this. Not sure if this is "best practice". Any suggestions on how to improve would be greatly appreciated.

I have an Item Class

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a webservice call that returns me a list of Item from another method in the Controller class.

```
public ActionResult GetDetails()
        {
            //Test filling List. Will be retrieved from Web Service eventually.
            testItemList = new List<Item>();
            testItemList.Add(new Item() { Id = 1, Name = "Bike", Price = new decimal(1000) });
            testItemList.Add(new Item() { Id = 2, Name = "Wheel", Price = new decimal(99.99) });
            testItemList.Add(new Item() { Id = 3, Name = "Saddle", Price = new decimal(49.99) });


            TempData["itemList"] = testItemList;
            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }
```

This puts the List and currentIndex into TempData through OnResultExecuted

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
    {
        TempData["testItemList"] = testItemList;
        TempData["currIndex"] = currentIndex;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details()
{
    testItemList = (IList<Item>)TempData["itemList"];
    currentIndex = (int)TempData["currIndex"];

    return View(testItemList[currentIndex]);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(string next, string back)
{
    var testItem = testItemList[currentIndex];

    if (TryUpdateModel(testItem))
    {
        if (next != null)
        {
            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) == testItemList.Count ? currentIndex : currentIndex + 1;
        }

        if (back != null)
        {
            currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1) < 0 ? currentIndex : currentIndex - 1;
        }

        TempData["currIndex"] = currentIndex;
        TempData["itemList"] = testItemList;

        return RedirectToAction("Details"); 
    }

    TempData["currIndex"] = currentIndex;
    TempData["itemList"] = testItemList;

    return View(testItem);
}
```

And then on the View I am serializing both the List and the current index so that I can keep track of it.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var listSerialized = Request.Form["itemList"];
    if (listSerialized != null)
    {
        testItemList = (IList<Item>)new MvcSerializer().Deserialize(listSerialized);
    }

    var indexSerialized = Request.Form["currIndex"];
    if (indexSerialized != null)
    {
        currentIndex = (int)new MvcSerializer().Deserialize(indexSerialized);
    }
    else
    {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }

}
```

View

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ArrayTest.Models.Item>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Details
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Details</h2>
    <% int Index = (int)TempData["currIndex"]; %>    
    <% var ItemList = (List<ArrayTest.Models.Item>)TempData["itemList"]; %>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       {%>       
    <%: Html.Serialize("itemList",ItemList) %>
    <%: Html.Serialize("currIndex",Index) %>    
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>
    <p>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(t => t.Name) %></p>
    <p>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(t => t.Price) %></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Back" name="back" />
    <input type="submit" value="Next" name="next" />
    <%} %>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on the complexity of your form and whether you need to store the temporary data and possibly save if the user needs to half-fill the form and come back another time.

I personally would favour a **client-side Wizard** using various [jquery wizard plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/formwizard) available. [jQuery lightbox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) while not meant for wizard, can be used for it. This has a few advantages:

- Number of calls limited to one final call and user can do as many amendments he wishes. So in terms of web service calls is optimum.
- Lends itself better to server side technologies such as ASP NET MVC
- It can allow for a half-filled form saving with an easy implementation.

But it requires pretty good client side validation to minimise round-trips due to invalid date but nowadays there are tens of tools you can choose for robust client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a server-side wizard, try this out:

Let's say you have a model that will be filled when the wizard is complete.

```
// This is a pseudo-model to show the properties Member has in this example.
// I use entity framework when generating my model objects. How you generate
// your model objects is not important in this example.
public class Member
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ReferredBy { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

I put together a simple model called `Member` that our wizard is going to populate in the end. Now I'm going to build a view model to be used on our wizard pages.

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public Member NewMember { get; set; }
    public int Step { get; set; } //int cannot be null and will be 0 by default.
}
```

Now I am going to build some action methods.

```
// First request will pull up the first view of the wizard with 
// a new RegisterViewModel.
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult RegisterNewMember()
{
    return View("RegisterWizardStep1", new RegisterViewModel());
}

// This will be the post action method. Rather than create a different
// action method for every step of the wizard, our view model will support
// which step we are on and this method will be aware of what to do.
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult RegisterNewMember(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (viewModel.Step < 2)
            return View(String.Format("RegisterWizardStep{0}", viewModel.Step + 1), viewModel);
        else
        {
            db.Members.AddObject(viewModel.NewMember);
            db.SaveChanges();
            // db is a fictional context. The syntax is that of entity framework.
            // You could substitute this for a LINQ to SQL context or any other
            // data storage component.
            ViewBag.WelcomeMessage = "Thank you for registering. We welcome you!";
            return View("Welcome");
        }
    }
    else
        return View(String.Format("RegisterWizardStep{0}", viewModel.Step));
        // Assuming you have model validation set up, returning the same view with
        // an invalid modelstate will trigger your validation helpers.
}
```

In this example I want three steps in the wizard. Consequently we will have three views.

First Step 1.

```
// RegisterWizardStep0
@model AppName.Models.RegisterNewMember
@using AppName.Models;
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Master.cshtml";
}

@* I'm not going to worry much about formatting in these views as they are only samples.
   I am also not going to worry about client-side validation before step submission;
   I will let you worry about that. *@

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <text>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Step)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewMember.Username)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewMember.Username)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewMember.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewMember.FirstName)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewMember.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewMember.LastName)
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
    </text>
}
```

And now Step 2.

```
// RegisterWizardStep1
@model AppName.Models.RegisterNewMember
@using AppName.Models;
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Master.cshtml";
}

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <text>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Step)

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Member.Username)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NewMember.FirstName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NewMember.LastName)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewMember.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewMember.Email)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewMember.ReferredBy)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewMember.ReferredBy)
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
    </text>
}
```

And finally Step 3.

```
// RegisterWizardStep2
@model AppName.Models.RegisterViewModel
@using AppName.Models;
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Master.cshtml";
}

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <text>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Step)

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NewMember.Username)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NewMember.FirstName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NewMember.LastName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NewMember.Email)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NewMember.ReferredBy)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewMember.Address)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewMember.Address)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewMember.City)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewMember.City)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewMember.State)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewMember.State)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewMember.Country)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.NewMember.Country)
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Done" />
    </text>
}
```

Hope this helps. Please note that I have not tested this code in an IDE as I'm not on my development computer. I'm sure it requires tweaks, but you get the idea.